# Try...Catch block which handles the triggered error for excel data that is not in the right format when imported

Tags: vb.net, error-handling

So I have a code-block that currently checks to see whether an excel file is present at a given location and if present, imports its contents into a list-box. If absent, it triggers an error message. I'm using the Try...catch code block to execute this.

I want to trigger an error message when the data to be imported is not in the appropriate format. The code block is below. Any help will be deeply appreciated.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click_1(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles butImport.Click
     Dim MyFileDialog As New System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog

    ' Configure the dialog to show both text and excel files
    ' Set its title and set the filename field blank for the moment.
    MyFileDialog.Filter = "(*.xlsx)|*.xlsx"
    MyFileDialog.Title = " Open an excel file"
    MyFileDialog.FileName = ""
    ' Show the dialog and see if the user pressed ok.

    If MyFileDialog.ShowDialog() = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
        ' Check to see if they selected a file and that it exists.

        If File.Exists(MyFileDialog.FileName) Then

            Dim strFile As String = MyFileDialog.FileName
            Dim textextension As String
            Dim testFile As System.IO.FileInfo
            Try
                ' Setup a file stream reader to read the text file.

                textextension = Path.GetExtension(strFile)
                If textextension = ".xlsx" Then
                    Dim oExcel As Object = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
                    Dim oBook As Object = oExcel.Workbooks.Open(strFile)
                    Dim oSheet As Object = oBook.Worksheets(1)
                    Dim i As Integer
                    Dim cellA As String
                    Dim cellB As String
                    Dim cellC As String
                    Dim cellD As String
                    Dim cellE As String
                    lstGradeLength.Items.Add("Grade (in Radians)" & vbTab & "   Length (in Miles)" & vbTab & vbTab & "Radius (in Feet)" & vbTab & vbTab & "Super-elevation (in Decimal)" & vbTab & vbTab & "Angle (in Degrees)")
                    For i = 0 To AscW(lstGradeLength.Items.Count.ToString()(i = i + 1)) - 1

                        cellA = "A" & Convert.ToString(i + 1)
                        cellB = "B" & Convert.ToString(i + 1)
                        cellC = "C" & Convert.ToString(i + 1)
                        cellD = "D" & Convert.ToString(i + 1)
                        cellE = "E" & Convert.ToString(i + 1)
                        cellA = oSheet.Range(cellA).Value
                        cellB = oSheet.Range(cellB).Value
                        cellC = oSheet.Range(cellC).Value
                        cellD = oSheet.Range(cellD).Value
                        cellE = oSheet.Range(cellE).Value
                        If cellA = "" And cellB = "" And cellC = "" And cellD = "" And cellE = "" Then
                            Exit For
                        Else
                            RichTextBox1.AppendText(cellA & " " & cellB & " " & cellC & " " & cellD & " " & cellE & vbCrLf)

                        End If
                    Next
                    oExcel.Quit()
                    Dim m As Integer
                    For m = 1 To CInt(UBound(RichTextBox1.Lines))
                        ReDim Preserve Grade(m)
                        ReDim Preserve Length(m)
                        ReDim Preserve Radius(m)
                        ReDim Preserve Superelevation(m)
                        ReDim Preserve Angle(m)
                        Grade(m) = RichTextBox1.Lines(m - 1).Split(" ").First
                        Length(m) = RichTextBox1.Lines(m - 1).Split(" "c)(1)
                        Radius(m) = RichTextBox1.Lines(m - 1).Split(" "c)(2)
                        Superelevation(m) = RichTextBox1.Lines(m - 1).Split(" ")(3)
                        Angle(m) = RichTextBox1.Lines(m - 1).Split(" ")(4)
                        lstGradeLength.Items.Add(Grade(m) & vbTab & vbTab & vbTab & Length(m) & vbTab & vbTab & vbTab & Radius(m) & vbTab & vbTab & vbTab & Superelevation(m) & vbTab & vbTab & vbTab & Angle(m) & vbCrLf)
                        butGradeLength.Enabled = False
                    Next
                    testFile = My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFileInfo(strFile)

                    lblPath.Text = testFile.FullName

                    txtNumSections.Text = lstGradeLength.Items.Count - 1
                End If

            Catch ex As FileNotFoundException

                ' If the file was not found, tell the user.

                MessageBox.Show("File was Not found. Please try again.")

            End Try

        End If
    Else
        txtNumSections.Text = ""
        butImport.Enabled = True
        butGradeLength.Enabled = True
        butClear.Enabled = True
        Exit Sub
    End If

    butImport.Enabled = False
    butCompute.Enabled = True
End Sub
```

Comment: You can have multiple catch clauses for different exception types in the same try block.  At the least you should have the base catch ex as exception as the last catch

Comment: @Hursey, thanks for your input. I added two Try catch blocks and it worked. The edited code is below;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Private Sub Button1_Click_1(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles butImport.Click
    Dim MyFileDialog As New System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog

    ' Configure the dialog to show only excel files
    ' Set its title and set the filename field blank for the moment.
    MyFileDialog.Filter = "(*.xlsx)|*.xlsx"
    MyFileDialog.Title = " Open an excel file"
    MyFileDialog.FileName = ""
    ' Show the dialog and see if the user pressed ok.

    If MyFileDialog.ShowDialog() = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
        ' Check to see if they selected a file and that it exists.

        If File.Exists(MyFileDialog.FileName) Then

            Dim strFile As String = MyFileDialog.FileName
            Dim textextension As String
            Dim testFile As System.IO.FileInfo
            Try
                'Setup a file stream reader to read the excel file.
                textextension = Path.GetExtension(strFile)
                If textextension = ".xlsx" Then
                    Dim oExcel As Object = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
                    Dim oBook As Object = oExcel.Workbooks.Open(strFile)
                    Dim oSheet As Object = oBook.Worksheets(1)
                    Dim i As Integer
                    Dim cellA As String
                    Dim cellB As String
                    Dim cellC As String
                    Dim cellD As String
                    Dim cellE As String
                    lstGradeLength.Items.Add("Grade (in Radians)" & vbTab & "   Length (in Miles)" & vbTab & vbTab & "Radius (in Feet)" & vbTab & vbTab & "Super-elevation (in Decimal)" & vbTab & vbTab & "Angle (in Degrees)")
                    For i = 0 To AscW(lstGradeLength.Items.Count.ToString()(i = i + 1)) - 1

                        cellA = "A" & Convert.ToString(i + 1)
                        cellB = "B" & Convert.ToString(i + 1)
                        cellC = "C" & Convert.ToString(i + 1)
                        cellD = "D" & Convert.ToString(i + 1)
                        cellE = "E" & Convert.ToString(i + 1)
                        cellA = oSheet.Range(cellA).Value
                        cellB = oSheet.Range(cellB).Value
                        cellC = oSheet.Range(cellC).Value
                        cellD = oSheet.Range(cellD).Value
                        cellE = oSheet.Range(cellE).Value
                        If cellA = "" And cellB = "" And cellC = "" And cellD = "" And cellE = "" Then
                            Exit For
                        Else
                            RichTextBox1.AppendText(cellA & " " & cellB & " " & cellC & " " & cellD & " " & cellE & vbCrLf)

                        End If
                    Next
                    oExcel.Quit()
                End If
            Catch ex As FileNotFoundException

                ' If the file was not found, tell the user.

                MessageBox.Show("File was not found. Please try again.")

            End Try

            Try
                'Setup a file stream reader to read the excel file.
                textextension = Path.GetExtension(strFile)
                If textextension = ".xlsx" Then

                    Dim m As Integer
                    For m = 1 To CInt(UBound(RichTextBox1.Lines))
                        ReDim Preserve Grade(m)
                        ReDim Preserve Length(m)
                        ReDim Preserve Radius(m)
                        ReDim Preserve Superelevation(m)
                        ReDim Preserve Angle(m)
                        Grade(m) = RichTextBox1.Lines(m - 1).Split(" ").First
                        Length(m) = RichTextBox1.Lines(m - 1).Split(" "c)(1)
                        Radius(m) = RichTextBox1.Lines(m - 1).Split(" "c)(2)
                        Superelevation(m) = RichTextBox1.Lines(m - 1).Split(" ")(3)
                        Angle(m) = RichTextBox1.Lines(m - 1).Split(" ")(4)
                        lstGradeLength.Items.Add(Grade(m) & vbTab & vbTab & vbTab & Length(m) & vbTab & vbTab & vbTab & Radius(m) & vbTab & vbTab & vbTab & Superelevation(m) & vbTab & vbTab & vbTab & Angle(m) & vbCrLf)
                        butGradeLength.Enabled = False
                    Next
                    testFile = My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFileInfo(strFile)

                    lblPath.Text = testFile.FullName

                    txtNumSections.Text = lstGradeLength.Items.Count - 1
                End If
            Catch ex As Exception
                ' If the data is in an incorrect format, tell the user.

                MessageBox.Show("Data is in incorrect format")
            End Try
            lstGradeLength.Items.Clear()
        End If
    Else
        txtNumSections.Text = ""
        butImport.Enabled = True
        butGradeLength.Enabled = True
        butClear.Enabled = True
        Exit Sub
    End If

    butImport.Enabled = False
    butCompute.Enabled = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

While it is good to have at least one generic exception handler, I don't see the point of catching FileNotFoundException since you are testing the file existence with `If File.Exists(MyFileDialog.FileName) Then` just before. Of course plenty of bad things can happen during program execution but I don't think there is any reason to handle this exception in particular since it is unlikely to happen.

And in fact if this condition is not met: `If File.Exists(MyFileDialog.FileName) Then` then your program does not even alert the user, it just resets a few UI controls. A simplified view of your block is like this:

```
If MyFileDialog.ShowDialog() = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
    ' Check to see if they selected a file and that it exists.

    If File.Exists(MyFileDialog.FileName) Then
        ...
    End If
Else
    txtNumSections.Text = ""
    butImport.Enabled = True
    butGradeLength.Enabled = True
    butClear.Enabled = True
    Exit Sub
End If
```

I am not sure this is what you want. If you let the user pick a file, but they play games by removing or renaming the file maybe you should alert them, not just ignore this little problem. At least the program is not going to crash on this exception but it is still an unexpected condition.